# Pandas Iterate through rows from specified row number

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iterator

I want to read data from a pandas dataframe by iterating through the rows starting from a specific row number. I know there's [`df.iterrows()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html), but it doesn't let me specify from where I want to start iterating.

In my specific case, I have a csv file that might look something like this:

```
Date, Temperature
21/08/2017 17:00:00,5.53
21/08/2017 18:00:00,5.58
21/08/2017 19:00:00,4.80
21/08/2017 20:00:00,4.59
21/08/2017 21:00:00,3.72
21/08/2017 22:00:00,3.95
21/08/2017 23:00:00,3.11
22/08/2017 00:00:00,3.07
22/08/2017 01:00:00,2.80
22/08/2017 02:00:00,2.75
22/08/2017 03:00:00,2.79
22/08/2017 04:00:00,2.76
22/08/2017 05:00:00,2.76
22/08/2017 06:00:00,3.06
22/08/2017 07:00:00,3.88
```

I want to loop through every row from a specific point in time on (let's say midnight of August 22nd), so I tried implementing it like this:

```js
df = pandas.read_csv('file.csv')
start_date = '22/08/2017 00:00:00'

// since it's sorted, I figured I could use binary search
result = pandas.Series(df['Date']).searchsorted(start_date)
```

`result[0]` actually gives me the correct number.

I guess what I could do then is just increment that number and access the row through `df.iloc[[x]]`, but I feel dirty doing that.

```
for x in range(result[0], len(df)):
    row = df.loc[[x]]
```

All answers I've found so far only show how to iterate the whole table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just filter your dataframe before calling `iterrows()`:

```
df['Date'] = pandas.to_datetime(df['Date'])
for idx, row in df[df['Date'] >= '2017-08-22'].iterrows():
    #
    # Whatever you want to do in the loop goes here
    #
```

Note that it isn't necessary to convert the filtering argument `'2017-08-22'` to a `datetime` object, because Pandas can handle [partial string indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#partial-string-indexing).

Comment: +1 because it works even if the exact datetime I'm looking for isn't in the table. Just a heads up that it compares strings alphabetically - if turned into a datetime it works fine.

Comment: I assume you're talking about if the column `Date` is datetime object, not a string.  You're right, I was assuming that.  I'll update the post.

Comment: Should've been more specific about that. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 6):

Turn `Date` into `datetime`.  Set `Date` as the `index`:

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)

df = df.set_index('Date')
```

Then:

```
for date, row in df['22/08/2017 00:00:00':].iterrows():
    print(date.strftime('%c'), row.squeeze())

Tue Aug 22 00:00:00 2017 3.07
Tue Aug 22 01:00:00 2017 2.8
Tue Aug 22 02:00:00 2017 2.75
Tue Aug 22 03:00:00 2017 2.79
Tue Aug 22 04:00:00 2017 2.76
Tue Aug 22 05:00:00 2017 2.76
Tue Aug 22 06:00:00 2017 3.06
Tue Aug 22 07:00:00 2017 3.88
```