# How to read csv file from a specific row using iterrows in python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am new to python and I wonder how to read the csv file from a specific row in the file. Actually I found a previous question from here: [Pandas Iterate through rows from specified row number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45990046/pandas-iterate-through-rows-from-specified-row-number) but it seems It is not exactly my case as I dont have specific date to start but it should be good to start with index.

For my case I have a csv file containing 1000 rows as the following code below:

```
import pandas as pd
file_read = pd.read_csv('1000_rows.csv')

for line,row in file_read.iterrows():
    print(line)
```

I think perhaps there is a way to set the condition with **file_read** but I dont know how to do it I want to start from line 400th so the print line in the `for` loop should print 400. Is there any way to do this? Thank you so much for your Help.

Comment: You do know that `file_read = pd.read_csv('1000_rows.csv')` creates a dataframe from your CSV, right?

Comment: If you don't convert to a dataframe you can't use `iterrows()`.

Comment: Ahh okay but in my case I dont have date to start like the previous question is there a way to start perhaps sth like **file_read.index** and set it to start from 400 for example?

Comment: @Ben10 just use [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing) and slicing - `file_read.iloc[400:]`

Comment: just ```for line,row in file_read.iloc[400:].iterrows():``` work fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address rows by index, simply use the handy [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) function and slicing:

```
import pandas as pd
file_read = pd.read_csv('1000_rows.csv')

for line,row in file_read.iloc[400:].iterrows():
    print(line)
```